# Steps to use Windows 7 as file server?

Tags: windows-7

My 15 user company wants to setup a simple file server / NAS.

As we have so few users, they do not want to purchase Windows Server 2008 R2. We already have Windows 7 Professional licenses.

So, my question is could I configure Windows 7 Professional as a file server?

If yes then how could i configure this? Is there any tutorial or step by step configuration that can help me?

Comment: This question is to vague. You're not going to get an answer that 'does all the work for you'. I suggest doing your own research and ask a more specific question if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and get a 4-disk Synology or QNap or Thecus NAS box.
(Configure those disks in RAID5 and be done with it.)
They costs less then a Win7 PC and for your use-case they are much better suited and MUCH easier to maintain.

And don't forget backup. 
Easiest is a 2nd NAS box. And just backup 1 NAS to the other. The backup doesn't need RAID so can do with less (or cheaper) disks.

Comment: Yes, I'd highly advise using a proper commercial NAS box if possible rather than mess about with a desktop computer. If you can't do that, and feel confident enough, I would suggest a Linux/BSD based NAS OS with disks configured in a redundant setup rather than Windows 7. (But of course still backup regardless of the NAS device used).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can file share with up to 20 clients using Windows 7, it's a terrible idea, I'd advise against it but yes you can, simply create a share - that's it - nothing more to do. If this is too hard then you need to get some basic training - either way this site isn't for you.

Comment: This exactly. And the fact that you want to use Win 7 Pro points to you using consumer desktop hardware which is a pretty poor idea for a file server. You don't need to spend millions, but it would be very much in your interest to buy a pro system with some basic RAID.

Comment: Actually, it's way more important to have a proper backup system in place that even basic RAID. I'd take a file server with JBOD storage but with properly setup backup over a RAID-6 array any time.

Comment: @Stephane It depends a bit on the use-case. If the backup-frequency is low compared to the update frequency of the data (or if restore from backup is very slow) I rather have RAID on the primary. But ANY backup beats NO backup all the time.

Comment: @Tonny Frankly, the only use case where RAID is more important that proper backup is when you're just setting up a cache. If the backup frequency is inadequate, then that must be fixed. RAID is only there to improve uptime and counting on it for protection against data lose is a receipt for disaster.

Comment: @Stephane RAID != BACKUP. You don't have to tell me that. What I meant: fixing backup-frequency is not always an option, because of cost and/or technical issues. In that case I always push on having RAID instead of JBOD to improve uptime during hardware issues. Of course someone hitting "rm- fr /" still requires proper backup. If a customer wants to do without backup at all, he can go looking for another consultant. I will flatly refuse to work like that. (I have done that 3 times. Lost 2 of those as client, the 3rd one came back after thinking it over and we implemented backup anyway.)

Comment: @Tonny So, in short, you're saying that RAID != backup except when it's cheaper/more convenient to do RAID than proper backup, am I correct ? Honestly, a backup that is inadequate is little better than no backup and money should be spent on fixing THAT before spending money on redundancy of the storage subsystem.

Comment: @Stephane Did you actually read what I wrote ? What I said is: 1-Always have backup. 2-If backup is sub-par because of constraints that can't be fixed I will prefer RAID over JBOD. 3-Fixing an inadequate backup is not always just a matter of money (and in todays economy just money is constraint enough). Regulations can demand a backup method/solution with is just not up to the job. Unfortunately government regulations are often written years ago against a state of technology that was already outdated at that time.